# Store permanent data on a php file to reduce the number of SQL queries is a good practice?

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design

I´m creating a new website and in the webs I´ve coded before I always have been using a php file to store permanent that is used a lot that is called with an include from the index.php.

The purpose of that is to avoid doing extra queries as this data is used every time and doesn´t change, but now I´ve concerns if that is a good practice.

One example of that is the different languages options that the website has, that is shown everytime and I don´t want to do an extra query every time.

Is that a good practise or it´s better to store everything on the DB and make more queries?

Comment: If you are talking about constants that are used on almost every page it's a good idea. In case of language selection example, this probably ought to be in your template instead of PHP

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean with "template"? It means in SQL table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after 3 years since I posted the question, I end up storing the data the following way:

- Almost all the data is stored in the mysql database, where it's easy to manage.
- I use the $_SESSION var only for user's data that is being called and used during the user's session only.
- I have a php file where I store general data that's being use a lot by the code and won't be changed in the short or mid term. This way I save the code to do several queries to the database. I store them within a function so they can be retrieved by other function and avoiding to declare them as a *global*. As an example:

  ```
  function retrieve_privacy_list(){
  $privacy_list = array(
      1=>'public',
      2=>'reduced',
      3=>'private');
  return $privacy_list;
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I store my language dependent strings in separate files, grouped by function, for example email.  So I would have a template called

```
lng_email
```

Then I add a suffix to it in the include statement.  For English the example would be

```
lng_email_en.php
```

The suffix is fetched at login and stored in the session variable.